Parser to collect information from the notcoin Telegram bot mini-application for new pools
I am developing a bot intermediary between the notcoin mini-application and a Telegram channel. My task is to notify my created channel about new pools that appear in the notcoin_bot Telegram bot.
1
What I tried to do
main.py:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import asyncio
import logging
import bot

load_dotenv()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    asyncio.run(bot.start())

bot.py:
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from os import environ
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.client.default import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


dp = Dispatcher()

additional_message = "Join now to start earning!"
channel_id = ""
sent_announcements = []
check_interval = 60 * 60

#Function triggered by the "/start" command
async def start():
    global bot
    #Create a Bot instance using the Telegram API token from environment variables
    bot = Bot(
        environ.get("TOKEN"),
        default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML),
)

    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

@dp.message(CommandStart())
#Function handling messages with the "/start" command
async def getUserByID(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"Hello, Ваш ID: {message.from_user.id}")

#Function to fetch and parse pool data
async def fetch_and_parse_pools():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://t.me/notcoin_bot") as response:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "html.parser")

    pools = soup.find_all("div", class_="pool")
    for pool in pools:
        pool_name = pool.find("h3").text
        pool_reward = pool.find("span", class_="reward").text
    
        if pool_name not in sent_announcements:
            sent_announcements.append(pool_name)

            announcement_text = f"**Новый пул:** {pool_name} | **Награда:** {pool_reward} в   час.\n{additional_message}"
            await bot.send_message(channel_id, announcement_text)


#Function to schedule pool checking (improved version)
async def scheduled(delay):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(fetch_and_parse_pools())

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(scheduled(check_interval))

In the process of coding, I tried to complete the task and tested the code, but apart from the greeting, none of the logic of the code worked.

What format should I use?

Are you sure that you use a correct URL to parse?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Какой формат url мне следует использовать?
